# Entity Framework - Adding parent is also trying to add child when I don't want it to

Tags: entity-framework

I have two objects (WishListItem and Product) in a one-to-many relationship.  WishListItem has to have a product.  Each Product can be in 0 - n WishListItems.

```
public class WishListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ... other properties
}
```

The Product has no knowledge of WishListItems. All of the Products exist. I just want to add a new WishListItem. My WishListItem model for the relationship is this:

`HasRequired(p => p.Product).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);`

When I try to add a new item like this:

```
WishListItem item = new WishListItem();

// ... sets properties

WishListItems.Add(item);  // WishListItems is of type DbSet<WishListItem>

SaveChanges();
```

This code seems to try to also add a Product. I don't want to add a new Product (or even update it). The Product property is set to null. How do I tell Entity Framework that I only want to add the WishListItem? Do I need to Ignore the Product property (by doing `Ignore(p => p.Product);` in my WishListItem model) and load the Product separately whenever I load my WishListItem objects?

Comment: the product should be optional in that case, so it should be this.HasOptional(....) and ProductId should be a nullable int

Comment: I tried `HasOptional(p => p.Product).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.ProductId);` with the same result. The ProductId is actually a string but I condensed the classes so you can easily see what I'm doing rather than a bunch of properties that don't have anything to do with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue. The problem came from another property on the Product object.

```
private bool _isFreeShippingInitialValue;

public bool IsFreeShipping
{
    get
    {
        return _isFreeShippingInitialValue ||
            computedValueFromAnotherChildObject;
    }
    set
    {
        _isFreeShippingInitialValue = value;
    }
}
```

We noticed that when you first get the Product object, the `IsFreeShipping.get` is called (not sure why) before any child objects are loaded. For example, if `_isFreeShippingInitialValue` is false and `computedValueFromAnotherChildObject` is true, `IsFreeShipping` first returns false (because `computedValueFromAnotherChildObject` is first false since no child objects have been loaded), then true the next time you try to get `IsFreeShipping`. This makes EF think the value has changed.

The first item we added to `WishListItems` worked fine. It was the second item that broke. We believe `SaveChanges()` (or something prior to it) loaded the Product for the first `WishListItem`. The `SaveChanges()` was breaking on the Product of the first `WishListItem` when we were adding the second item.

So, in short, be careful when computing values in a `Property.get` using child objects because it can bite you in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without adding any new Addresses records. In this model, Person has an optional home address, but address doesn't have any knowledge of the person.

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public int HomeAddress_id { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

In the `DbContext` override, I have the below code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.HomeAddress).WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.HomeAddress_id);
}
```

I can write a unit test like this.

```
var addressId = 0;
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    var address = new Address { City = "test", Country = "test", PhoneNumber = "test", State = "test", Street = "test" };
    db.Addresses.Add(address);
    db.SaveChanges();
    addressId = address.Id;
}

using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    var person = new Person { Email = "test@test.com", FirstName = "Testy", LastName = "Tester", HomeAddress_id = addressId };
    db.Persons.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();                             
}
```

Comment: what if you set the HomeAddress_id to an existing Address. In my case, even though I don't want to add or update a product, I do need to supply the ProductId.  The WishListItem has to have a Product associated with it.

Comment: in that case person has a required home address, i have updated the code above.